# Selecting child element

Tags: jquery

I have the following div

```
       <div id="acc">
           <a href="#">Link 1</a>
           <div>
                Some Content
           </div>
           <a href="#">Link 2</a>
           <div>
               Some Content
           </div>
       </div>
```

All the div's are collapsed to start with. How can I select the first div child of 'acc' and say Slide Down on it

I have cached the selector like this:

var $acc = $(acc);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [first selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) (or [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)) and combine that with the [children method](http://api.jquery.com/children/):

```
$(acc).children('div:first').slideDown();
```

If you just want a single selector, then checkout the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$('#acc > div:first').slideDown();
```

---

> how can I change it to slide up all div's except the first one.

Rather than try to find *all-except*, you may find it easier to mark the so-called "active" `div`:

```
$(acc).children('div:first').addClass('active').slideDown();
```

And find the previously marked div:

```
$(acc).find('.active').removeClass('active').slideUp();
```

However, if your goal is to create an accordion effect, you'll probably save yourself a lot of headaches by using a completed solution, such as [jQuery UI's Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) or any of [numerous plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/accordion+type:project_project).

Comment: thanks and how can I change it to slide up all div's except the first one . this is not working $(acc).children('div:not(:first)').slideUp();

Comment: I added an id to first div but am unable to achieve it. How to slide up all div's except the first one with the id?

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#acc").children().first().hide().slideDown('slow',function(){
                    // animation complete...
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="acc">
           <a href="#">Link 1</a>
           <div>
                Some Content
           </div>
           <a href="#">Link 2</a>
           <div>
               Some Content
           </div>
       </div>

    </body>
</html>
```